# Open semaphore without changing its value

Tags: c, linux, posix

Opening a semaphore with `sem_open` will also initialize it to any given value, is there any way to open a semaphore that is used by another thread without changing its value?

Comment: Don't specify `O_CREAT` in any opener you want to open, not create, the semaphore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you say isn't true. Using `sem_open` to open an existing semaphore doesn't change its value.

So, to answer you question,

```c
sem_t *sem = sem_open( name, O_RDWR );
if ( sem == SEM_FAILED ) {
   perror( NULL );
   exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
}
```